# Why Fontawesome showing box only

Tags: html, font-awesome

my fontawesome is not working, its only show box.
i tried the latest cdn and fontawesome kit but its not working.

`<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/387afd28f2.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`
this is my latest kit.

here is where i put my icon

`

#### CONTACT DETAILS

8 123-456 Loc. 611 /
 612 0912 345 6789

```
                <i class="fa-light fa-envelope"></i><p>
                    info@tourismheritage.com</p>

                <i class="fa-sharp fa-regular fa-clock-rotate-left"></i><p>
                    8:00 AM - 5:00 PM (Mon - Sat)</p>
                
                <i class="fa-light fa-location-dot"></i><p>
                    Unit 123, Sample address, for presentation purposes only.</p>
            </div>`
```

Im sorry Guys to bother or disturb everyone im beginner.

Comment: You need to include the CDN link to font-awesome CSS.